# Calling launch file from node during runtime

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Based on some condition in node, I want to start and stop [hector slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) . (in parallel)

I had looked at different [questions](http://answers.ros.org/question/28867/startstop-node-at-runtime/) and [rosspawn](http://wiki.ros.org/rosspawn) but couldn't figure it out.

```
if(start_node == true)
{
// start node in parallel 
// Here my case is hector SLAM
}
if (stop_node == true)
{
// Stop the node
}
```

Any suggestions  ?

thanks.

**Edit ::**

I found starting node in another package in `python` code from [Roslaunch-API Usage](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage). I am looking for similar way in C++ also starting nodes with params and arguments.

```
import roslaunch

package = 'rqt_gui'
executable = 'rqt_gui'
node = roslaunch.core.Node(package, executable)

launch = roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch()
launch.start()

process = launch.launch(node)
print process.is_alive()
process.stop()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193197/calling-launch-file-from-node-during-runtime/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there is no right way to start and stop nodes dynamically. If you're writing the nodes yourself, it's much better to include pause/resume functionality via services.

As @Ricky stated, you can use the system call, however system will block until the command finishes, meaning you have to use the `&` control operator in the command to spin off a new process. Then you have the issue of trying to track down/parse the PID in order to shutdown when necessary.

I would recommend using Qt's [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html#running-a-process), which will make it easier to manage the state of the process (destructing the object will kill the roslaunch process, thus shutting down the nodes).

---

EDIT: Poco also has nice looking [Process](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Process.html) management, if you want to avoid messing with Qt. ROS's [class_loader CMakeLists](https://github.com/ros/class_loader/blob/indigo-devel/CMakeLists.txt) is an example of how to include Poco in your package.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
Hi Paul, thanks for answer, `poco` looks better than using direct linux commands, i will try it out. But its not the ROS way of doing.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-12-10**:
The problem with writing everything as a service is that ROS can be a memory hog. Even small trivial nodes, doing nothing, can consume 4% of memory. Get a few dozen of those, and you're already out of memory even though your bot's just sitting there doing nothing.